# Scrape information from meta and button tags with rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the average user ratings (out of 5 stars) and number of ratings from a wine seller's page. The average stars our of 5 seems to be in a `button` tag while the number of rating is in a `meta` tag.
Here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="bv_avgRating_component_container notranslate">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="bv_avgRating"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="average rating value is 4.5 of 5."
      id="avg-rating-button"
      role="link"
      itemprop="ratingValue"
    >
      4.5
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="bv_numReviews_component_container">
    <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="95" />
   &nbsp;
   <button
      type="button"
      class="bv_numReviews_text"
      aria-label="Read 95 Reviews"
      aria-expanded="false"
      id="num-reviews-button"
      role="link"
    >
      (95)
    </button>
  </div>
```

What I've tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

x <- "/wine/red-wine/cabernet-sauvignon/amici-cabernet-sauvignon-napa/p/20095750?s=918&igrules=true"
ratings <- read_html(paste0("https://www.totalwine.com", x)) %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//meta[@itemprop="reviewCount"]') %>% 
  html_attr('content') #returns character(empty)

ratings <- read_html(paste0("https://www.totalwine.com", x)) %>% 
  html_nodes("meta") %>% 
  html_attr("content") #returns chr [1:33]

ratings <- read_html(paste0("https://www.totalwine.com", x)) %>% 
  html_nodes("div meta") %>% 
  html_attr("content") #returns chr [1:21]

ratings <- read_html(paste0("https://www.totalwine.com", x)) %>% 
  html_nodes("meta[itemprop=reviewCount]") %>% 
  html_attr("content") #returns character(empty)
```

At the end of the day, the two points I am trying to extract are `4.5` and `content="95"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Network tab of Dev Tool and reload the page, you'll see that this page loads data from `https://www.totalwine.com/product/api/product/product-detail/v1/getProduct/20095750-1?shoppingMethod=INSTORE_PICKUP&state=US-CA&storeId=918` (which is a JSON file):
[image]
Get the rating and review count you want by this:

```
data <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.totalwine.com/product/api/product/product-detail/v1/getProduct/20095750-1?shoppingMethod=INSTORE_PICKUP&state=US-CA&storeId=918")
rating <- data$customerAverageRating
reviews_count <- data$customerReviewsCount
```

**Update:** If you're new to the web-scraping field, you're probably wondering why I didn't use `rvest` at all. The thing is, this page uses JS to generate the content and `rvest` cannot handle JS, it only reads the HTML before JS loaded.

Comment: thank you @xwhitelight ! I didn't know the bit about JS. This chunk is part of a function where i intend to get 20 different variables for ~5k wines. The JSON appears to have all the information I need so this is super helpful! All i need to do is set the product ID (20095750) in the path as my arg. Can i ask how you knew it was that specific URL that had information?

Comment: @laBouz After opening the Network tab and reloading the page, there are quite a lot of requests show up. That's where the "experience" comes in, I kinda guess what request contains the information. Note that it's not necessary that there's always a request contains the information you need.