# Scraping website with html_text() and html_node() gives empty return

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, rvest, xml2

I would like to scrape all addresses from a website. I can see the addresses on the website, but somehow cannot navigate to them. If I navigate further, the navigation with `html_nodes()` doesn't work anymore and just stays at the point after three levels.

The code that I execute is:

```
mpreis <- "https://www.mpreis.at/sp/standorte"
addresses_vector = c()

x <- GET(url=mpreis)
html_doc <- read_html(x)
  
addresses_vector <- c(addresses_vector, html_doc %>%
    rvest::html_nodes(xpath="body/div/main")%>%
    xml2::xml_find_all(xpath="//*[contains(@class, 'c3-market-list__item-address')]")%>%
    rvest::html_text())
```

I tried to navigate to the element I'm interested in using several different options of xpath-notation and css notation but `html_text()` always returns an empty vector because `html_nodes()` does not navigate to the node inteded.

Any help on why I cannot navigate to the specific node with that class or any other ideas, why the content I see on the website is returned as empty in R is appreciated!

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861669/scrape-information-from-meta-and-button-tags-with-rvest/63861807#63861807

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really get your point @xwhitelight.

Comment: Read my answer to that question. This question follows the same concept.

Comment: The data you want is from here: `https://cms-storefront.mpreis.at/typo3conf/ext/template/Resources/Public/Location/current.json`

Comment: Thank you a lot @xwhitelight! It solves my problem but I don't get how you know the address of the `.json` file. I know that in your last answer you said it's experience, but could you tell me how to find out if not so experienced? :)

Comment: What I usually do is searching for the data's content in the Network tab (press Ctrl-F). It will address where the data is located. (When I wrote that answer, I didn't know that trick)